# How to define a global array (which gets length another function)?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, global-variables

How I can write a C code which has a global array that takes its length from main() as a user input?

I tried so many different ways but none of them worked so far, one for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int length;
int array[length];

int main()
{
    scanf("%d",&length);
}
```

Comment: You can't do it that way as `length` is undefined when you declare `array`. You could use [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) instead.

Comment: First, you have declared `length` as `const` why do you expect that you could change / assign to it? (Although the `const` is not entirely responsible for your problem here)

Answer (score 7):

Referring to your code, I can point to this:

```
int array[length];
```

This won't work of course because, at the compile time, the size of the `array` is unknown. You can't define an array with indefinite (From Compiler's perspective during compilation) size statically!
If you want to decide the size of array run-time (i.e. dynamically), you can't do that by means of declaring a variable the way you have done.

Also, using `const` with `length` won't work here. Get rid of `const`.

What you can and should do is, take an `int` pointer, and get the starting address of the memory that gets dynamically allocated. 
You can use [`malloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) function for that.

I won't write the whole code for you, but it should contain which looks something similar to this:

```
int *ptr = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
```

From here, if user has entered 10 (i.e. `length` = 10) for example, **and** if `malloc` doesn't return `NULL`, then you should be able to store upto 10 integers starting from address stored in `ptr` pointer, and of course access them by incrementing the pointer `ptr`.

If you read through any of the manual pages for `malloc` you should be able to deal with what header file you need. I am not writing what file you need, because I want you to read the man page and code for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You obviously can't. When `length` gets its value, do you expect the memory allocation to magically happen backwards in time, retroactively?

That's just not how C works, it's not that abstract.

You have to make the array just a pointer (which you can then declare `extern` where needed), and have the length as a separate variable, also `extern`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays declared at file scope (outside the body of any function) have `static` storage duration, meaning the space for them is allocated as soon as the program starts, before any statements have been executed.  Because of this, their sizes must be known at compile time.

If you want to allocate memory that's globally visible, but not sized until runtime, you'll have to use dynamic memory allocation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *array;     // personally, I would name these something like
size_t length;  // g_array and g_length to emphasize their "global-ness"
                // and disambiguate them from any local variables.

int main( void )
{
  // get length value somehow

  array = malloc( sizeof *array * length );
  if ( !array )
  {
    // Could not allocate memory, handle as appropriate
  }

  // do stuff with array

  free( array );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a dynamic array using malloc to solve the problem, as example shown in the following.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int *array;
main()
{
    int length;
    scanf("%d",&length);
    array = (int *)malloc (length*sizeof(int));
    // array[0] = 100;
}
```

I am assuming your array length fit in the range of integer, or change accordingly.

Comment: It is not `studio.h`, it is `stdio.h`. The correct prototype of main is `int main(void)`, not `main()`. You should not cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.